# Prove that if $f'(x)≠0$ on an interval $( a , b)$ on $A$ for a differentiable function $f$, then $f$ is one-to-one on $A$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Prove that if $f'(x)≠0$ on an interval $( a , b)$ on $A$ for a differentiable function $f$, then $f$ is one-to-one on $A$.

I was wondering whether the proof in the attached picture is correct. Could anyone please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. If $f$ is not one-to-one on $(a,b)$ then there exist two distinct points $x,y \in (a,b)$ satisfying $f(x) = f(y)$. But there exists a point $z$ in between $x$ and $y$ satisfying $$0 = \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} = f'(z) \not= 0$$ which is the contradiction you need.

There is no reason for $f(a) = f(b)$ to hold.

Comment: But that's the assumption you have to make in order to prove it right? One-to-one means *if* f(a)=f(b) *then* a=b. So you can assume f(a)=f(b) right?

Comment: No - in fact $f$ isn't even defined at $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Can you please explain why you can't make the assumption that f(a)=f(b)? It's necessary for a function to be injective right?

Answer (score -2):

Your pictured proof just shows that $f$ is injective.  You now have to show it is surjective as well.

Comment: The question stated only asks to show the function is one-to-one.

Comment: One to one is equivalent to injective **and** surjective.

Comment: Only insofar as all functions are surjective when the codomain is limited to be the range of the function.

Comment: "One to one correspondence" is injective and surjective, at least in my experience. "One to one" is simply injective. (The ambiguity being a big reason why I prefer to use injective, surjective, and bijective.)